# Use Snapchat Pixel without User Email or Phonenumber

Tags: php, wordpress, ads, facebook-pixel, snapchat

I'm currently working a Pixel for my site and don't know how I set it up without a user email or phone number? The Pixel requires one or both of these parameters to work properly.

I want to track how good my ads actually convert. When a user comes from an ad to my site, he is not logged in so I can't have any information about it and the Pixel sends errors. Only after his registration I can send these parameters.

Is there a proper way to fix this issue or do I just got it wrong in my head?

Edit:

```
<!-- Snap Pixel Code -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(e,t,n){if(e.snaptr)return;var a=e.snaptr=function()
{a.handleRequest?a.handleRequest.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)};
a.queue=[];var s='script';r=t.createElement(s);r.async=!0;
r.src=n;var u=t.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
u.parentNode.insertBefore(r,u);})(window,document,
'https://sc-static.net/scevent.min.js');

snaptr('init', 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx', {
'user_email': '__INSERT_USER_EMAIL__'
});

snaptr('track', 'PAGE_VIEW');

</script>
<!-- End Snap Pixel Code -->
```

I've successfully installed the pixel and I'm receiving events, but they can't get matched because the email parameter is not set.
This happens when a user visits my site who is not logged in. If he logs in I can use his mail adress and the issue is solved.

Comment: Have you tried calling `init` again when you have the email? That works well with the facebook pixel which otherwise has the same undocumented issue.